# Devise + Omniauth for google only login

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm developing a web application that will interact with google APIs.

Since the only way to use the application is though a google account I want to only allow login through a google account.

I think I'll be using the "omniauth-google-oauth2" strategy, since OAuth2 is the preferred way to access google APIs.
To handle the login itself I'd like to use Devise, since I don't like to write it from scratch (thus reinventing the wheel and having to care with all security issues related to a login system).

My questions is can I disable Devise login for non-google accounts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your User model you will have a line that looks like this:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
```

What you want to do is simply remove the strategies you don't want. An explaination of what each one is can be found on the [devise repository's page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Effectively, you want to keep `:omniauthable` and remove `:database_authenticatable` which provides password-based authentication.

Comment: If you are creating a new model, be sure to remove them from your migration as well, no point in creating extra columns.